# Why does String Field return null

Tags: arrays, field

I am trying to make a text based game, I want to create a system that keeps track of location using an array, I need to turn string input of direction from the end user into an update for the location
I don't have a long background in java programming and I am returning to it after a long time so I have forgotten how things like constructors and fields work.
this is the jist of the main thing.

```
static int[] pos = {0, 0, 0};
public static String Direction;
public static String Action;
public static String navigation;
public static String Input;

public static void main (String [] args)


{
  System.out.print(pos[0] + ":" + pos[1] + ":" + pos[2]);
  String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("hello");
  Input = input;
  System.out.println(input);
  System.out.println(Input);
  System.out.println(Direction);
  System.out.println(pos[0] + ":" + pos[1] + ":" + pos[2]);
 


 }
public static void Position()
{
 if ("N".equals(Direction)){pos[1] = pos[1]++;}
}



public String Translator(String Direc, String Act)


{
if ("North".equals(Input)){Direction = "N"; System.out.println("Succeed");}
if ("South".equals(Input)){Direction = "S";}
if ("West".equals(Input)){Direction = "W";}
if ("East".equals(Input)){Direction = "E";}
if ("north".equals(Input)){Direction = "N";}
if ("south".equals(Input)){Direction = "S";}
if ("west".equals(Input)){Direction = "W";}
if ("east".equals(Input)){Direction = "E";}
Direction = Direc; 
    return Direction;
```

}

```
Output:
0:0:0North
North
null
0:0:0
```

null should be "N" and 0:0:0 at the end should be 0:1:0

Comment: Retrace each step. Why output should not be `null`? The field 'Direction' is never assigned, unless `Translator` routine, which is never called. Even there, `Direction` is being immediately overwritten by content of `Direc`, so, it never will be `N` it will be `North`

Comment: you are not initializing it with a value